# How to detect JAILBROKEN/ROOTED device in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, jailbreak, rooted-device

Is there any way to detect JAILBROKEN/ROOTED device (both in android and ios) through **NativeScript**? I tried searching but could not find any library. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Update: Basically I wanted to know basic checks that I can put in my code for jailbreak/root detection in ios and android.
I got what I was looking for from some other documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the following files/path exist:

1. /Applications/Cydia.app (file)
2. /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib (file)
3. /bin/bash   (path)
4. /usr/sbin/sshd   (path)
5. /etc/apt   (path)
6. /private/var/lib/apt/   (path)

Comment: And it will not work if none of that is installed or installed in a different location like some jailbreaks actually do.

Comment: With xcode (only for iOS) you can check with a library but for yuor purpose I know only this way

Comment: @PrimaAlessandro Thanks for your input. Added similar conditions for jail break detection in ios.

Answer (score -1):

You touch upon a requirement! If you request that in [forum](https://discourse.nativescript.org) - [community](https://nativescriptcommunity.slack.com) or GitHub , we may see plugin soon..
You want a plugin like [JailMonkey](https://github.com/GantMan/jail-monkey) library for ReactNative. Maybe it inspires you to create your own solution(review).